# Android Volley: assign response to variable outside of inner class

Tags: android, android-volley

I know this question has been asked so many times, but I still can't figure out how to pass a volley response to an outside variable.

Let me show you a simplified example what I need:

**MainFragment.java**

```
List<String> grabbedMovies = new ArrayList<>();

MovieGrabber.getMovies("https://example.com/movies.json", getContext(), new MovieGrabber.MovieGrabberCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<String> response_movies) {
            grabbedMovies = response_movies;
        }
    });

// do some other fancy stuff with grabbedMovies
```

This code produces an error which tells me that **variable is accessed from within inner class and needs to be declared final**. That's what I did, so obviously `grabbedMovies = response_movies` will not work anymore since it's final, so I modified the code as follows:

```
final List<String> grabbedMovies = new ArrayList<>();

MovieGrabber.getMovies("https://example.com/movies.json", getContext(), new MovieGrabber.MovieGrabberCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<String> response_movies) {
            for(Iterator<String> i = response_movies.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                String item = i.next();
                grabbedMovies.add(item);
            }
        }
    });

 // do some other fancy stuff with grabbedMovies
```

But... as a result, `grabbedMovies` is still empty.

I also tried to define `grabbedMovies` as a global variable - right after `public class MainFragment extends BrowseFragment {`  without the final declaration.

So please, can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

**MovieGrabber.java** (for the sake of completeness )

```
public final class MovieGrabber {

    public static void getMovies(String url, final Context context, final MovieGrabberCallback callback) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        List<String> movies = new ArrayList<>();
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("SOME_PATTERN");
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);

                        while(matcher.find()) {
                            movies.add(matcher.group());
                        }

                        callback.onSuccess(movies);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        RequestSingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

    public interface MovieGrabberCallback{
        void onSuccess(List<String> response_movies);
    }
```

#### if it helps:

I'm playing around with the the standard project for Android TV in Android Studio. There's a function `setupMovies` in `MovieList.java` that has hardcoded movies in it, and I'm trying to extend it with a REST-call.

Comment: `Pattern.compile("SOME_PATTERN")` Are you actually using `"SOME_PATTERN"` as the regular expression pattern?

Comment: LOL, no... for the sake of simplicity, I removed it, to avoid people putting to much focus on that line ;-)